# Can I rely on the navigation tutorials when working with sonar?

Tags: ros, navigation, ubuntu, raspberrypi, ubuntu-trusty

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I have setup a robot running Ubuntu 14.04 on a Raspberry Pi 2 with Ros indigo. I want my robot to make a map of the surroundings and then navigate in it. I have Sonar and not laser scanners.

This Ros tutorial about publishing sensor streams over Ros assume that the robot is using a laser but what if it is using a Sonar?

Here's the link : http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Sensors

Do I need to write the code myself?

If I need, then where to write? Do I write it just similar to the one described in the tutorial? And how do I mention the gpio pin numbering and all those for my rpi to understand?

Please help and correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks & Regards
Mukut

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231269/can-i-rely-on-the-navigation-tutorials-when-working-with-sonar?/) by [mukut_noob](https://answers.ros.org/users/26182/mukut_noob/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2016-04-07

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are asking multiple questions, please split them, I will focus on the navigation part:

Sonar probably just won't work since they cover a large area, a single Bottle will mark a large area as occupied, what you can do is

1. configure the costmap to use [Range Sensor Layer](http://wiki.ros.org/range_sensor_layer) instead of the usual laser based obstacle_layer. See the [the Layered costmap tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/Tutorials/Configuring%20Layered%20Costmaps) on how to do that.
2. Do not use amcl/gmapping and use /odom as the global frame.
3. Paint the map yourself with e.g. Inkscape and feed that to the map

Afaik there currently is no single tutorial for this, so this requires a lot of reading, it probably would be a good idea to write one.

---

Originally posted by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) with karma: 1504 on 2016-04-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mukut_noob](https://answers.ros.org/users/26182/mukut_noob/) on 2016-04-07**:
Okay thank you so much!! I will try it out and let you know....thank you!

**Comment by [mukut_noob](https://answers.ros.org/users/26182/mukut_noob/) on 2016-04-07**:
U mean I should not use gmapping package? Then what shall I use in order to make the robot I told earlier?

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2016-04-07**:
gmapping is to record a map from Laserscan, without one you can only manually paint one.

**Comment by [mukut_noob](https://answers.ros.org/users/26182/mukut_noob/) on 2016-04-07**:
Okok...so in that case I need to use something like lnkspace?

**Comment by [mukut_noob](https://answers.ros.org/users/26182/mukut_noob/) on 2016-04-07**:
Lnkscape* are there any tutorials on it?

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2016-04-07**:
Inkscape was just an example, just use your favorite painting program to draw the lines for the walls etc. But thats the least of your problems now, you should focus on the other parts, e.g. publishing sonar data first.

**Comment by [mukut_noob](https://answers.ros.org/users/26182/mukut_noob/) on 2016-04-07**:
Ohh...okay..

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short answer: yes, you can!

In Ros, the navigation packages requires a [costmap](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d) to work. This costmap can be built using different sensors, as LIDARs, RGBD cams, infrareds, sonars, etc... The sensor of choice will affect the quality of your costmap and therefore, the quality of your navigation.

If you need to create your own driver for your ultrasound sensor, you need to populate and publish a [range message](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Range.html). I believe you can follow the mentioned tutorial to get an idea on how to construct and populate a message, but changing the type from LaserScan to a Range message.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2016-04-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mukut_noob](https://answers.ros.org/users/26182/mukut_noob/) on 2016-04-07**:
Okay thank you so much!! I will try it out and let you know....thank you!

**Comment by [mukut_noob](https://answers.ros.org/users/26182/mukut_noob/) on 2016-04-07**:
So I need to follow and use those parameters and write my own code? Right? So can it be in python? Please correct me if I am wrong.

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2016-04-07**:
yes, you can use python. what you have to do is to get the raw info from your sonar, use it to populate your range message and publish it. by doing that you will have a node that will publish your sonar data as a ros topic, which can be used by many other nodes.

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2016-04-07**:
@Humpelstilzchen post is very useful on what you can do after having that topic and effectively using it for navigation.

**Comment by [mukut_noob](https://answers.ros.org/users/26182/mukut_noob/) on 2016-04-07**:
But are there some detailed guide on how to populate the range and publish it? Or can you tell a little? It would help a lot.

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2016-04-07**:
you can get the idea of how to populate a ros message from the tutorial you mentioned in your question.

**Comment by [mukut_noob](https://answers.ros.org/users/26182/mukut_noob/) on 2016-04-07**:
So I can use any editor and write the code, then save it in my catkin workspace under sensor_msgs and then include it in the launch file that would populate the message and send it over Ros. Right?

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2016-04-08**:
no, that's not the way. forget about ros for a while. what you need is a code that will get the data from a sensor, using whatever means you have available, and populate a message structure and publish it. i suggest you go back to more basic tutorials before advancing on this issue.

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2016-04-08**:
and also search around on this site, because you can find examples on what you are trying to do, as in [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/114731/sensor_msgsrange/)

**Comment by [mukut_noob](https://answers.ros.org/users/26182/mukut_noob/) on 2016-04-08**:
You said "what you need is a code that will get the data from a sensor, using whatever means you have available, and populate a message structure and publish it." So my question is that is that going to be in a single file or the code that would get the data from the sensor would be one file....

**Comment by [mukut_noob](https://answers.ros.org/users/26182/mukut_noob/) on 2016-04-08**:
.....and the other would be the one that populate the message and publish it? Please help me I may be wrong and very irritating...even though I fall back to the tutorials I fairly understand everything.